# belongsTo relationship returns null

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a table called `Locins` (locations) which has a foreign key to another table called `Rgn` (regions).

So in my Locin model:

```
class Locin extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Locin';

    protected $primaryKey = 'Locin_id';

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function Rgn()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Rgn', 'RgnID', 'RgnID');
    }
}
```

and in my Rgn Model:

```
class Rgn extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Rgns';

    protected $primaryKey = 'RgnID';

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function Locin()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Locin', 'RgnID', 'RgnID');
    }

}
```

When I say: `$location = Locin::find($request->Locin);` a location is returned successfully. (I var_dumped it).

But then when I say `$location->Rgn` it returns null.

Tables structure:

Locins Table: [Locin_id (primary key), RgnID (foreign key), *other unrelated fields*].

Rgns Table: [RgnID (primary key), *other unrelated fields*]

What am I doing wrong?

**edit**
It turns out that the stupid seed in the DB had a foreign key for an entry that does not exist.
I am tired of getting stuck on silly things. Sorry and have a good day.

Comment: Your table Locin has the RgnID column and one record with an existing RgnID?

Comment: my Locin table has many records with existing RgnIDs and the particular one I'm testing on sure has an RgnID of value 35.

Comment: Does `Rgn::find($location->RgnID)` return a `Rgn` record, or null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see what the query is running for the region, it is a way of testing processes:

```
\DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
$location = Locin::find(1);

$region = $location->Rgn;

$query = \DB::getQueryLog();
$lastQuery = end($query);

dd($lastQuery);
```

You get something like this

```
array:3 [
    "query" => "select * from `Rgns` where `Rgns`.`RgnID` = ? limit 1"
    "bindings" => array:1 [▼
        0 => 1
    ]
    "time" => 0.5
]
```

And replacing the value of `bindings` in the query you could run the output directly to your database to see if the query is correct

```
Select * from `Rgns` where `Rgns`.`RgnID` = 1 limit 1
```

Comment: Thank you! this sounds super useful. for some reason it returns that:
`
array:3 [▼
  "query" => "select * from `Rgns` where `Rgns`.`RgnID` = ? limit 1"
  "bindings" => array:1 [▼
    0 => 0
  ]
  "time" => 3.19
]
`
So a `?` as the RgnID.

Comment: @AdamZahran The `?` is a parameter placeholder. `bindings` tell you what values are injected into those parameters. In the example given by Alfredo, the `bindings` show that the value `1` would be injected. In the output you've shown, the value `0` is being injected. This means that the `Locins.RgnID` of the record you tested is 0.

Comment: you guys were super helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have set both relationship columns to 'RgnID' for each relationship. I'm guessing it should be something else.

Remember it is:

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Whatever', 'foreign_key', 'other_key');
```

Comment: In `Locin` there is a field called RgnID that references the primary key in the Rgns table which happens to be called RgnID as well. I wish you were right but that's not the case.

Comment: I hope this doesn't come across as rude because that's definitely not my intention but if you have control of the schema and this is something new you are building, it's worth it to follow proper naming conventions.  Name your models `Location` and `Region`, primary keys should be named `id` and foreign key in your `locations` table should be `region_id`.  Then you don't need to worry about any of this, all you need is the model name.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from. I actually have the very same feeling about all this but unfortunately this is an already existing project that I'm working on and have to stick to the predefined database naming.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fetching the region by the location model then you should use the **eager loading** (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) of the related model by using this

```
$location = Locin::where('Locin_id', $request->Locin)->with('Rgn')->get();
```

Hope this helps you to find a very quick solution.